# OpenCV - Apply method in BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 crashes Android Application after 5-10 seconds

Tags: android, opencv

I am developing one `Android application using OpenCV` where I have to implement Background Subtraction. I am able to see some frames in grayscale and background removed, it only lasts for a while though, and then the application crashes.
`Technique used: BackgroundSubtractorMOG2`

This is my snippet of OnCameraFrame

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {


    Mat frame = inputFrame.rgba();
    Mat mRgb = new Mat();
    Mat mFGMask = new Mat();
    BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 mog2 = Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, mRgb, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB); 
    mog2.apply(mRgb, mFGMask); 
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mFGMask, frame, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA);

    return frame;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my issue. 
new Mat() which is used was causing an issue of memory management.  It has to be initialized just once in onCameraViewStarted and the returning Mat has to be released in onCameraViewStopped. After modifying the code as per suggestions through the OpenCV community, I was able to execute my application properly.
1. Declare at the first

```
private Mat mRgb;
private Mat mFGMask;
private Mat frame;
private BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 mog2;
```

2. Initialize in onCameraViewStarted

   public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {

   ```
   mRgb = new Mat();
   mFGMask = new Mat();
   mog2 = Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
   ```

   }
3. Release the returning frame in onCameraViewStopped

   public void onCameraViewStopped() {

   ```
   frame.release();
   ```

   }

For full code: https://github.com/rishirajrsawant/OpenCV-Background-Subtraction